# Error "Speculative Devirtualization via Guarded Calls", What and Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode 9.4 and Swift 4.1. But while I am trying to archive the app for App Store build. It is throwing and error.

[image]

and here is The code around line no 46

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var attributes = [String: AnyObject]()
        attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.red;

        self.setAndUpdateViewsData(self.kristal);


        self.lExpandableSummary.numberOfLines = 2;
        self.lExpandableSummary.collapsed = true;
        self.lExpandableSummary.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "show more", attributes: attributes);
        self.lExpandableSummary.expandedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "show less", attributes: attributes);
        self.lExpandableSummary.ellipsis = NSAttributedString(string: " ...");
//        self.lExpandableSummary.setLessLinkWith(lessLink: "show less", attributes: attributes, position: nil);

        self.lDesclaimer.numberOfLines = 2;
        self.lDesclaimer.collapsed = true;
        self.lDesclaimer.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "show more", attributes: attributes);
        self.lDesclaimer.expandedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "show less", attributes: attributes);
        self.lDesclaimer.ellipsis = NSAttributedString(string: " ...")
//        self.lDesclaimer.setLessLinkWith(lessLink: "show less",attributes: attributes, position: nil);


    }
```

Comment: i am having same issue any update??

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel? I had to turn off Swift optimization to be able to archive the project, I'm using this component too.